# vue + pure html component?

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component

how to implement vue-cli calling pure html method?

Please check below as sample file. because I have custom pure html code and facing difficulty converting it to vuejs.

product.vue

```
<template>
    <custombutton @childclick="childclick" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
   component: { custombutton },
   methods: {
    childclick(value) {
         console.log(value)
       }
   }
}
</script>
```

custombutton.html

```
<html>
<body>
 <button @click="childclick" />
</body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<script>
var App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      vueMessage: 'testing vue message',
    }
  },

  methods: {
    childclick() {
       this.$emit('childclick', 'success!')
    }

  },
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to preserve the possibility to call Vue component from both .html file and .vue files, I would recommend moving your Vue logic from `custombutton.html` file into a separate `custombutton.js` file, which will export an object representing Vue component previously defined in HTML. You can then import `custombutton.js` both in `custombutton.html` and `product.vue`.

Example:

`custombutton.js`:

```
export default {
  name: 'CustomButton',
  template: '<div>Hello world!</div>'
}
```

`custombutton.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>App</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="module">
    import CustomButton from "./custombutton.js"
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      components: { CustomButton },
      template: '<CustomButton />'
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`product.vue`:

```
<template>
    <CustomButton />
</template>

<script>
import CustomButton from "./custombutton.js"
export default {
   components: { CustomButton }
}
</script>
```

Note that:

- For `custombutton.html` to work target browsers should implement [ECMAScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).
- For `product.vue` to work you should set [`runtimeCompiler: true`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler) in your Vue CLI configuration. (Since the template in `custombutton.js` is defined as a string runtime compiler needs to be included in the final bundle.)
- It is important to find a suitable location for `custombutton.js` so it can be imported easily using relative paths from both `custombutton.html` and `custombutton.vue` files.
- Defining the template as a string in `custombutton.js` can be quite inconvenient, as you have no markup highlighting, however I don't see any workaround for this.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, but I want to make custombutton.html as standalone HTML and respond function to vue file. is it possible? Because I can't do in template: '<div>Hello world!</div>' in custombutton.js, there are many lines of code and include javascript method as well.
Something like vue (as parent) render iframe(pure html), and iframe button event response to parent

Comment: @anson I posted another answer which should better meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit more cumbersome, but allows template to be written with syntax highlighting into `<script>` element, which is more convenient than writing template as a string literal into a `template` property.

`custombutton.js`:

```js
export default {
  name: 'CustomButton',
  data: function () {
    return { testVar: 125 }
  }
}
```

`custombutton.component.html`:
The template is now located in `#custombutton-template` element. "Hello world! 125" should be printed out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>App</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script id="custombutton-template" type="x-template">
    <div>Hello world! {{ testVar }}</div>
  </script>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="module">
    import CustomButton from "./custombutton.js"
    CustomButton.template = "#custombutton-template"
    
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      components: { CustomButton },
      template: '<CustomButton />'
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`product.vue`: Thanks to Webpack config (see below) we are able to import contents of `custombutton.component.html` file as a string, parse it and get inner HTML of `#custombutton-template` element, which is the desired template.

```vue
<template>
    <CustomButton />
</template>

<script>
import CustomButton from "./custombutton.js"
import CustomButtonComponent from "./custombutton.component.html"

var el = document.createElement("html")
el.innerHTML = CustomButtonComponent
var template = el.querySelector("#custombutton-template").innerHTML
CustomButton.template = template

export default {
   components: { CustomButton }
}
</script>
```

Importing `custombutton.component.html` file as string is done by non-default Webpack `raw-loader`, therefore it is necessary to adjust Webpack config:

`vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.component\.html$/,
          use: ["raw-loader"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```